# FPC (lesti) won't holepunch certain area

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, full-page-cache, block-cache, holepunching

Working on a webshop with lesti:fpc + redis and magento caching.
Now i encounter the problem that (when lesti fpc is enabled) holepunching a certain module isn't working.

[image: Screenshot of certain page]

The part view2.phtml (Zeon_Manufacturer_Block_View) isn't working.
Other parts like the layered navigation, breadcrumbs the titel etc.. are working fine.

Is there a special way to set this up or whatever?
Cleaning the cache everytime i visit a brands page isn't working offcourse.
For now i use `Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType('block_html');`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the block name you want to "holepunch" in the Dynamic Blocks textarea under System > Configuration > System > Lesti FPC.

Lesti FPC also has lazy blocks, which is basically a cached dynamic block stored on the users session which reset on specific actions. more info here:

https://gordonlesti.com/what-are-lazy-and-dynamic-blocks-in-lesti-fpc/

Comment: Wow.. thanks. kind of embarrassed that i didn't figured it out in time.
I did put it in dynamic blocks before. i guess i didn't refresh or whatever.. :$